Specific value for an invertible matrix
I have been given the following matrix, and have been tasked with finding the values of "a" that makes it invertible. I know that for a matrix to be invertible, then the determinant of said matrix must not be equal to 0. So I find the determinant of A.
A=
$$ A =\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & -a & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
    -1 & 0 & 1&0\\ 
    0 & 1+a & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$
I HAVE to make it a upper triangular matrix (by the assignment), so I can find the determinant easily. I subtract the 4th column from the second
$$ A =\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & -a & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 0 & 2 \\
    -1 & 0 & 1&0\\ 
    0 & a & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$
I then want to take out "a" from the second column fourth row of the matrix, but can I just do the following?
$$ A =\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & -a & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 0 & 2 \\
    -1 & 0 & 1&0\\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix} (a)$$
After adding the third column to the first, I then get:
$$ A =\begin{pmatrix}
    1-a & 0 & -a & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 0 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & 1&0\\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix} (a)$$
Which makes det(A)= (1-a)(-1)(1)(1)(a). Am I correct in this?

No, it has an error. We have $\det(A)=(2a+1)(a-1)$. Try $a=0$ to see the difference to your calculation. You have then $\det(A)=0$, but obviously $A$ is invertible for $a=0$.

But when did my calculation go wrong? I made it an upper triangular matrix and then took of the diagonal entries.

The assignment said specifically to transform the matrix into an upper triangular matrix and then finding the values of a that makes it invertible. So I have to turn it into an upper triangular matrix.

Yes, you should turn it into an upper triangular matrix. But correctly. With $a=0$ you will see where you went wrong (or now read the answers).

$$A =\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & -a & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 0 & 2 \\
    -1 & 0 & 1&0\\ 
    0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{a} \\
    \end{pmatrix} (a)$$
You didn't consider $A_{24},A_{44}$.
You know what, it was better off without taking $a$ common.
$$A =\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & -a & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 0 & 2 \\
    -1 & 0 & 1&0\\ 
    0 & a & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$ This is well off. Taking discriminant w.r.t. to the $1^{st}$ column, we get $$D=1(-1×1+2(-a))+(-1)(a(-1-2a))$$
You can continue from here,using $D≠0$
OP I didn't see your comment saying that it required only a triangular matrix.You should have mentioned it in your post
In that case, proceed with $\frac{1}{a}$ as a term. Not 1.Add the $4^{th}$ row to the $2^{nd}$ row, to get a new $4^{th}$ row.
Hence:-
$$A =\begin{pmatrix}
    1-a & 0 & -a & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 0 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & 1&0\\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 2+\frac{1}{a} \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$
The product of the diagonal is $\frac{2a+1}{a}(a-1)$. Multiplying this with $a$ gives you $(a-1)(2a+1)$.

(2+1)(−1), which is the determinant, does not equal the diagonal product. Why is that?

@MarkusJ check now. I included how it equals to it.

Thank you, I get it now!


$$\begin{vmatrix}
        1 & 0 & -a & 0 \\
        0 & -1 & 0 & 2 \\
        -1 & 0 & 1&0\\ 
        0 & a & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{vmatrix}$$
is by no means equal to
$$a\begin{vmatrix}
        1 & 0 & -a & 0 \\
        0 & -1 & 0 & 2 \\
        -1 & 0 & 1&0\\ 
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{vmatrix}=a(a-1).$$
Moreover, your first step (subtract the fourth column from the second one) was a waste of time. It did not make any progress in your task to "make $A$ an upper triangular matrix".
Instead, starting from $A$, simply apply Gauss's algorithm: if $R_1,\dots,R_4$ denote the four rows of $A$, replacing $R_3$ by $R_3+R_1$ and $R_4$ by $R_4-(1+a)R_2$ leads to
$$\det A=\begin{vmatrix}
        1 & 0 & -a & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
        0 & 0 & 1-a&0\\ 
        0 &0& 0 & -1-2a
        \end{vmatrix}=(a-1)(2a+1).$$

